# Bulkloader syntax Error

Tags: formatting, load, syntax-error, bulkloader

Having been struggling trying to bulkload data to the datastore, I have reached the point where expert help is needed.

I don't think what is am doing is tricky, I have the following configuration file:

[image]

and when I use the appcfg.py command, the error messages end with:

```
File "config.txt", line 1
python_preamble:
               ^
Syntax error: invalid syntax.
```

I have used a .txt file as it is faster to edit in notepad initially - I don't know if that is a problem and the remote_api for the appspot all seems to be okay.

I am thinking it is a fairly fundemental problem as it has stopped working at the top line. I removed the comment lines at the top of the original file - maybe that caused it.

I have tried to find working examples to set me right but they all seem to follow the syntax above, or where they are slightly different, I have tried both variants.

Help on bulkloading for my first cloud app would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for anyone taking time to read my post whether they solve it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure the configuration file extension is .yaml